# js remove() удаляет сначала элементы внутри, а потом уже сам элемент, который нужно удалить по нажатию кнопки

Tags: javascript, html, css, javascript-events

Есть контейнер, внутри него него 3 блока(итема), внутри каждого блока есть кнопка, по нажатию которой срабатывает функция, которая должна удалить именно сам элемент, а она удаляет сначала внутренности этого блока, будь то кнопка по которой кликаешь или текст, а уже потом сам элемент. Как сделать чтобы удалялся только элемент?

```js
function f1() {
  elem = document.querySelector(".container");

  elem.addEventListener("click", event => {
    let el = event.target;
    el.remove()
  })
}
```

```css
.block {
  background-color: blue;
  color: black;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.del {
  color: white;
  font-size: 32px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block">
    <span>1</span> <span class="del" onclick="f1()">del</span>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="block">
    <span>2</span> <span class="del" onclick="f1()">del</span>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="block">
    <span>3</span> <span class="del" onclick="f1()">del</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это нужно?

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.del').forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('click', event => {      
      item.parentNode.remove()
  })
})
```

```css
.block {
  background-color: #a3b7c7;
  color: black;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.del {
  color: white;
  font-size: 32px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block">
    <span>1</span> <span class="del">del</span>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="block">
    <span>2</span> <span class="del">del</span>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="block">
    <span>3</span> <span class="del">del</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: имеенно  это, спасибо большое

Comment: Нет, конечно, не это. Не спасибо. Сколько обработчиков клика будет в конце концов у `.container`?

Comment: @Igor уже норм.

Comment: @ИльяKrike забыл убрать ваш `onclick` из разметки. Потому что мы слушателей вешаем итак, то функция не нужна. (см. ответ). Или функция нужна позарез?

Comment: В текущем варианте удаляется при клике в любом месте... `if (el.classList.contains("del")) //...`

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME да. я что-то уже устал кажется. переделал на норм вариант...вроде)